# How to send an erlang message to a websocket handler?

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy

I've been looking into Cowboy websockets in Erlang.

My goal is to send a websocket frame to an existing websocket connection.
I found docs under [Receiving Erlang messages](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.4/guide/ws_handlers/#_receiving_erlang_messages) stating that I can send an "Erlang message" and it will be handled by `websocket_info/2`.

What does this documentation mean by "Sending an Erlang message"?

I've tried something like:

```
init(Req, State) ->
  Self = self(),
  spawn(fun() ->
    timer:sleep(2000),
    Self ! "Hoii"
  end),
  {cowboy_websocket, Req, State}.

websocket_info(_Info, State) ->
  io:fwrite("Info received\n"),
  {ok, State}.
```

But this seems to do nothing.

How can I send an Erlang message for my `websocket_info/2` to handle for an existing websocket connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After just a few minutes, I figured out that I was simply sending the `self() ! "Msg"` too early.

Cowboy websockets also have a function `websocket_init/1` and by moving my code into that function I was able to recieve the `websocket_info/2` message.

```
websocket_init(State) ->
  Self = self(),
  spawn(fun() ->
    timer:sleep(2000),
    Self ! "Hoii"
  end),
  {ok, State}.

websocket_info(_Info, State) ->
  io:fwrite("Info received\n"),
  {ok, State}.
```

Note the message is being sent now from the `websocket_init/1` function rather than just `init/2`.